# How do I disable My Verizon access to my FiOS router?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, wireless-router, fios

I have a router given to me by Verizon, a FiOS Quantum Gateway. Verizon offers this feature where you can access some of your settings online through My Verizon, and change them from wherever you are. Note that this is different from remote access, where you specifically log in to the router through your public IP. Rather, this is all done from the Verizon website. However, this poses a slight privacy concern for me, and I'd like to disable it if possible.

I've taken a look through the router configuration UI and [the user guide](https://www.verizon.com/cs/groups/public/documents/adacct/fqgrouter-userguide.pdf) with no success, and none of the Verizon forums seem to mention this. Is there even a way to disable this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, Verizon is somewhat of a privacy concern these days.

This is how I handled it.

1. Called Verizon, had them switch the ONT to Ethernet.
2. Ran Ethernet to the location of the router.
3. Replaced the Verizon gateway with a Pfsense box.
4. (Optional) Put VZ router in its own isolated network in "moca bridge mode". This is so the cable boxes could still update the guides & still be able to use video on demand.
5. Started using dnscrypt
6. Added bonus, pfblockerNG package can be used to block all adds & most malicious sites from all devices on the network.

Please note: Going this route will lose your technical support from Verizon, they will tell you that they do not support your "advanced router". You should also make sure you get hardware that supports the speeds up/down you are currently paying for.

Comment: Hmm, this does address the privacy concern, but doesn't really answer the question. For reasons related to roommates, I need to keep the Verizon router. If there's no better answer I'll accept this one, thanks!

Comment: To clarify, this may be a bit of an XY problem: Really what I want is to avoid my roommate from being able to see what I'm doing with the router, as they are the one who has access to My Verizon (bill is in their name). I'm not trying to take control of the router or anything, but I don't want my traffic stats being accessible to my roommate from just anywhere.

Comment: Raw traffic, i.e how much total, and at what speed will be available to whoever has control of the main router.

Comment: I can't find any way to do this, so I'm going to accept this answer. Thanks for the input!

Comment: You are welcome!